# How to have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 on the same disk, without grub?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 22.04

When a computer has only one disk and we install Windows, then we remove this disk and add another one to install Ubuntu, then we add both disks to the computer, we have two operating systems where the boot is managed by uefi and there is no grub. I installed windows 10 and then Ubuntu 22.04 on the same disk, on different partitions, but Grub was also installed. I want to be able to choose which system I will use by default through the uefi boot and I don't want grub installed. How do I do this?

Comment: If you are using GPT instead of MBR, which is most likely for a disk with a modern Windows OS installed, then you likely cannot.

Comment: Also, why is GRUB problematic?

Comment: I want to choose which system will be booted by default by booting the motherboard setup instead of rebuilding Grub every time I want to change.

Comment: Grub is both a boot manager (menu) and boot loader. You normally have to have grub to boot Ubuntu. What do you mean rebuild grub. You should not need to change grub once installed. But Windows settings often prevent grub from booting Windows.

Comment: You can use 'LiLo', 'LoadLin', 'Burg', 'SysLinux'. See for instance https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj-k8Lomdb5AhUzgXMKHQgODr4QFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tecmint.com%2Fbest-linux-boot-loaders%2F&usg=AOvVaw3C5nmLlGfMYkkGivP5q_Fh. Or let your searchengine look for Linux Bootloaders.

Comment: You can do that by just depending on the BIOS boot menu and not grub, although you would need the right partition table, primary partitions not logical and better have different hard disk to just cut it to the chases.

Comment: My grub can boot windows or Ubuntu just fine so see if it works on your machine

Answer (score 0):

I use grub2win. It's a free app that you install in Windows that you can configure to boot other OSes. You can set any installed OS to boot as default unattended after a timeout that you set. When starting the PC you get a menu to select the OS, using the up and down arrow keys, then press enter. Or you can let it time out and boot whatever you set as default. I have 3 OSes in my system that I can choose with it.